# ValidationError in FormView Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

What is the correct way of raising the `ValidationError` in a `FormView` and passing it to the template with reloaded form?
Currently I have this:

```
class ProfileUpdateView(FormView):
    template_name = 'profile_update.html'
    form_class = UserDetailForm
    success_url = '/profile/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        userdetail = form.save(commit = False)
        try:
            already_exist_info = UserDetail.objects.get(document_type=userdetail.document_type,
                series=userdetail.series, number=userdetail.number)
            raise forms.ValidationError("Document already exists in DB")
        except UserDetail.DoesNotExist:
            [... some stuff here ...]
            userdetail.save()
        return super(ProfileUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

It works and I get the error page, but I would prefer to show the error in the template with reloaded form.
Moreover, is there a built-in way to get `ValidationError` in `FormView`? I mean, without importing `forms` from `django`.

Thanx.

**EDIT**

Well, I've decided to do all the trick in other manner - using `clear()` method. So now I have this:

***views.py***

```
class ProfileUpdateView(FormView):
    template_name = 'profile_update.html'
    form_class = UserDetailForm
    success_url = '/profile/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        userdetail = form.save(commit = False)
        #[... some stuff ...]
        userdetail.save()
        return super(ProfileUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

***forms.py***

```
class UserDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserDetail
        exclude = ('user', )

    def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super(UserDetailForm, self).clean()
            document_type = cleaned_data.get("document_type")
            series = cleaned_data.get("series")
            number = cleaned_data.get("number")
            try:
                already_exist_info = UserDetail.objects.get(document_type=document_type,
                    series=int(series), number=number)
                raise forms.ValidationError("Document already exists in DB")
            except:
                pass
            return cleaned_data
```

Everything seems to be fine according to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other), however this time the form just saves without any errors.

Comment: Did you try `form.add_error('field', 'error message')`?

Comment: Yeap, it doesn't work since I guess my error doesn't belong to a specific field...

Comment: Ok, try getting rid of form.save. Can't you just access the data with form.cleaned_data?

Comment: See my updates. Yes, I can. Now I do this in clean() method in forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raising `ValidationError` in the form's `clean` method is the correct approach.

Your problem is that you are catching *all* exceptions, including `ValidationError`. If you change your code to catch a more specific exception, then it should work.

```
try:
    already_exist_info = UserDetail.objects.get(
        document_type=document_type,
        series=int(series), 
        number=number,
    )
    raise forms.ValidationError("Document already exists in DB")
except UserDetail.DoesNotExist:
    pass
return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Will that work with the UpdateView if I use the form as `form_class`?

Comment: @RamiAlloush yes you should be able to do something similar in an update view. You may have to exclude the current object from the queryset (e.g. `.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)`.

Comment: If you’re still stuck please ask another question, I can’t help in the comments.